# Slide out input field on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a search input field set to opacity 0 that appears whenever I click on the search icon.

I would like to have it slide from the right instead of just appearing. And to slide back again whenever I click on the X icon or outside the element (anywhere in the document)

What is the best way to achieve that? Through jQuery or CSS animation?

**DEMO** https://jsfiddle.net/p1zLh65g/4/

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_sidebar" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown nav-categories"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>أقسام </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">رأي وتحليل</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">جدل</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">سلطة خامسة</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">تحقيق</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ثقافة</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">بصريات</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li class="nav-date"><a href="#">22 مارس 2017</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">EN </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">تسجيل الدخول</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#" class="slide"><i class="fa fa-search search-icon"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right search" placeholder="عن ماذا تبحث؟">
          <span class="input-group-btn"></span>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.search {
    opacity: 0;
}

input.form-control.pull-right.search.expanded {
    border-radius: 0;
    width: 300px;
}

.search.expanded {
    opacity: 1;
}

.nav-categories {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Javascript

```
$('.search-icon').click(function () {
  $('.search').toggleClass('expanded');
  $('.search-icon').toggleClass('fa-times');
});
```

Comment: This may be help you : https://codepen.io/nikhil/pen/qcyGF

Comment: Try using Animate.css. Simple and easy to use css transitions and you can add/toggle classes using jquery.
(https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Comment: you can achieve this with css only with transition on width

Comment: @melvindidit animate.css seems like the easy solution except the fact that the input field is sliding in from outside the container when I want it to slide from next to the search icon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here is a simple example using simple css3 transition along with your
>   jquery and bootstrap code.

**I have just added the `transition property` which makes the `animation` to work as wanted.**

```
.search {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
   -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
   transition: all .5s ease;
   width:0px;
}
```

Here is the working snippet [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2txxcpot/).